# Hiding the iOS keyboard in jQuery mobile/phonegap when selecting a different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I select a "select" input, then I tap the menu icon in the top left of my app, and the select option still stays displayed as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm a pleb. All I had to do:

```
$('select').blur();
```